# How to read service status in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, services, cron

I have written a script to monitor a specific service on my VPS. That service (clamd.amavisd) tends to be found unexpectedly dead and when it does, my e-mail service is essentially stopped.

I use the following instruction in the script:

```
STATUS_QUERY_RESULT_STRING=$(service $SERVICE_NAME status)
```

The problem is that, when run from the terminal, the script receives something in that variable (I have echoed it to a file so I would know) but unfortunately for me, when run in a cron job, the variable is empty.

It's obvious that I'm doing something wrong. Is there some factor that I'm not taking into account?

Comment: How is `$SERVICE_NAME` defined in the script?

Comment: I had this as the very first line of my script: `SERVICE_NAME=clamd.amavisd`. But the problem was that I wasn't using absolute paths to the `service` binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABSOLUTELY everything that you running from `cron` must have absolute paths because `cron` using a minimal part of environment variables

```
   STATUS_QUERY_RESULT_STRING=$(/full/path/to/service $SERVICE_NAME status)
```

You can actually set in your script most important PATHs you need as

```
   PATH=/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

but if you wont one day to find out that for example expected `ls` is in fact malicious hacker's drop then use always absolute paths

Assign in the beginning of your script that you willing to use something like that

```
   CAT='/bin/cat'
   LS='/bin/ls'
```

and use it as

```
  $LS -la /some/path
  $CAT /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Absolute paths to /sbin/service were the problem.